# How to align text buttons in HTML

Tags: html, text, alignment

I'm trying to align 3 text boxes horizontally, would love some advice/help!

These should all be in a row however it is stacking in a horizontal manner.

I belive it has something to do with the td and table tags.

```
 <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center">
     <tbody>

     <td align="left" style="color: #808488; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px">
       <a href="" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none">
       <table width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#00c0a5" style="border-radius:4px">
       <tbody>

 <td align="center" style="padding:15px 10px 15px 10px; color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; font-family:Arial">Repayment Calculator</td>



          <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center">


     <td align="middle" style="color: #808488; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px">
       <a href="" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none">
       <table width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#00c0a5" style="border-radius:4px">



 <td align="center" style="padding:15px 10px 15px 10px; color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; font-family:Arial">Borrowing Power Calculator</td>




             <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center">
     <tbody>

     <td align="right" style="color: #808488; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px">
       <a href="" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none">
       <table width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#00c0a5" style="border-radius:4px">
       <tbody>


 <td align="center" style="padding:15px 10px 15px 10px; color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; font-family:Arial">Property Report</td>
    </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
   </table></td>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using multiple tables/tables within tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center">
     <tbody>
 <td align="left" style="color: #808488; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; width:33%;">
       <a href="" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none">
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#00c0a5" style="border-radius:4px">
       <tbody>
<tr>
 <td align="center" style="padding:15px 10px 15px 10px; color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; font-family:Arial">Repayment Calculator</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
<td align="left" style="color: #808488; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; width:33%;">
          <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center">
<tbody>

<tr>

     <td align="middle" style="color: #808488; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px">
       <a href="" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none">
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#00c0a5" style="border-radius:4px">
<tbody>

<tr>
 <td align="center" style="padding:15px 10px 15px 10px; color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; font-family:Arial">Borrowing Power Calculator</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
<td style="width:33%;">


             <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center">
     <tbody><tr>

     <td align="right" style="color: #808488; font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px">
       <a href="" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none">
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#00c0a5" style="border-radius:4px">
       <tbody>
<tr>
 <td align="center" style="padding:15px 10px 15px 10px; color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; font-family:Arial">Property Report</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
 </tbody></table>
 </td>
    </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Nested tables are resulting into the ladder alignment, Above code cleanly closes the "table" tags and also width for "td" tag is adjusted to 33%.